# Autocreate new database rows

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

My application creates several rows of data per customer per day. Each row is modified as necessary using a form. Several modifications to a row may take place daily. At the end of the day the customer will "commit" the changes, at which point no further changes will be allowed. In each row I have a 'stage' field, stage=1 allows edits, stage=2 is committed, no further changes allows.

How can I update the stage value to 2 on commit?
In my model I have:

```
@property
def commit_stage(self):
    self.stage = 2
    self.save()
```

Is this the correct way to do this? And if so, how to I attach this function to a "commit" button.

Comment: When you say "attach a function", I'm not sure what you mean, but if I'm guessing right, you could give the button a value, say something like `Commit` and in your views, you can do `if request.POST['submit'] == 'Commit': #do commit code here`

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I'm used to saving data via a form. In this case I don't need a form as all of the data is in the database. I simply need to change the stage field when a button is clicked. So in part I'm wondering where the code actually goes. I'm guessing that I still need a 'form' to handle the post but I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are confused about what properties do. You should **absolutely not** attach this sort of functionality to a property. It would be extremely surprising behaviour for something which is supposed to retrieve a value from an instance to instead modify it and save it to the db.

You can of course put this in a standard model method. But it's so trivial there is no point in doing so.

In terms of "attaching it to a button", nothing in Django can be called from the front-end without a URL and a view. You need a view that accepts the ID of the model instance from a POST request, gets the instance and modifies its stage value, then saves it. There is nothing different from the form views you already use.